# Create msix package for a website using makeappx.exe

Tags: msix

I'm trying to create msix package for a website using makeappx.exe (eg: makeappx pack /d C:\temp\mywebsite /p C:\temp\mywebsite.msix)
What would be the executable value since this is website?
Here is my Application section from AppxManifest.xml

```
<Application Id="MyWebSite" Executable="MyWebSite" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
```

**Here is an error that I got:**

> MakeAppx : error: Error info: error C00CE169: App manifest validation
>   error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 23, Column
>   44, Reason: 'Mywebsite' violates pattern constraint of
>   '.+.([Ee][Xx][Ee])'. The attribute 'Executable' with value
>   'MyWebSite' failed to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set the **StartPage** attribute, not *Executable*, to point to your website.

Here you can find the [schema for the AppXManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-application) file, with more details on each attribute from the *Application* element.

Comment: Yes, replaced StartPage with Executable and delete EntryPoint has resolved an issue. Thanks :)